# Problema con listas en python (variable)

Tags: python, array, lista, variables, variables-globales

resulta que quiero modificar los valores de una lista, pero cuando los modifico se modifica el mismo valor repetido en esta lista. quisiera saber si existe la forma de hacer que cada variable de la lista sea independiente. o tambien como solucionar esto

```
Cm1 = ["C","D#","G"]
Ddim2 = ["D","F","G#"]
Dsos3 = ["D#", "G", "A#"]

chords = [Cm1,Ddim2,Dsos3,Cm1]
for note in range(0, len(chords[1])):
    chords[0][note] =chords[0][note] + "5"

print(chords)
```

El output es=

```
[['C5', 'D#5', 'G5'], ['D', 'F', 'G#'], ['D#', 'G', 'A#'], ['C5', 'D#5', 'G5']]
```

como vemos se modifica la variable en la lista en las 2 instancias de esta. pero necesito que cada una de ellas sea independiente, el resultado que necesito es:

```
[['C5', 'D#5', 'G5'], ['D', 'F', 'G#'], ['D#', 'G', 'A#'], ['C', 'D#', 'G']]
```

Gracias a todos de antemano!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En `Python`, las variables no contienen directamente los valores que asignamos, continene referencias a objetos que residen en memoria y pueden ser de diferentes tipos, por ejemplo entero (`int`), real (`float`), etc... Una lista también es un objeto. [Aquí](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-references/) hay un artículo que explica muy bien como funcionan las variables en `Python`. En otras palabras, una variable en `Python` es un apuntador a una sección de memoria donde existe el valor que estamos asignando.

Cuando creas:

```
Cm1 = ["C","D#","G"]
```

Estas creando una variable `Cm1` que apunta a un objeto de tipo lista que contiene los valores `["C","D#","G"]` y al asignarlo a `chords`

```
chords = [Cm1,Ddim2,Dsos3,Cm1]
```

Únicamente estas diciendo que `chords` tenga dos elementos que hacen referencia al mismo objeto, por eso cuando editas uno el otro se modifica.

Dos formas fáciles de evitar ese problema son:

1. Utilizar el método `copy()`:

```
chords = [Cm1.copy(), Ddim2.copy(), Dsos3.copy(), Cm1.copy()]
```

2. Utilizar la función `list()`:

```
chords = [list(Cm1), list(Ddim2), list(Dsos3), list(Cm1)]
```

Existen otras formas para hacerlo, como rebanadas y la función `copy.copy()` te dejo un [artículo](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python/copy-list-python/#:%7E:text=lista%20en%20Python.-,Copiar%20una%20lista%20en%20Python%20usando%20el%20m%C3%A9todo%20copy(),un%20duplicado%20de%20una%20lista.) que puede ser de ayuda.

Ejemplo completo utilizando el método `copy()`:

```
Cm1 = ["C","D#","G"]
Ddim2 = ["D","F","G#"]
Dsos3 = ["D#", "G", "A#"]

chords = [Cm1.copy(), Ddim2.copy(), Dsos3.copy(), Cm1.copy()]
for note in range(0, len(chords[1])):
    chords[0][note] =chords[0][note] + "5"

print(chords)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[['C5', 'D#5', 'G5'], ['D', 'F', 'G#'], ['D#', 'G', 'A#'], ['C', 'D#', 'G']]
```

Comment: Es importante tener en cuenta que el metodo copy devuelve una copia superficial. Es decir, copia la lista, pero no su contenido. Si aplicas copy a una lista de listas, las sublistas no se copiaran.